# Compiler showing "Expression must have a constant value" in VS2015 (C Programming)

Tags: c

So i wanted to create a swap function that will allocation size of character array dynamically. Is it possible? Is it recommended?
My code that shows errors.

```
void swap(void * vp1, void * vp2, int size)
{
    char buffer[size];  //size must have a constant value is the error i am getting.
    memcpy(buffer, vp1, size);
    memcpy(vp1, vp2, size);
    memcpy(vp2, buffer, size);
}
```

Comment: Variable length arrays are not supported natively. Use a vector for C++ or malloc for C

Comment: Why are you using void pointers? Please choose either C or C++

Comment: I don't know c++... Can you please tell me how would I use Malloc here?

Comment: Then why have you tagged it C++?

Comment: @ed heal because I don't just want to swap integers.. What if string or floating values?

Comment: But C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Sorry my  bad. I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: You will need to write a family of functions for the different data types in C. (to be type safe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char buffer[size];
```

An array whose size is not known at compile time is known as a *variable length array*. These are C-only features. Since this is giving an error, you are using a C++ compiler. You must change `size` so that it will be known at compile time.

The following are valid C++ array definitions

```
#define NUM 8
int a[16];
int a[NUM];
```

This is ill-formed:

```
int n;
printf("What is your age?\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

int a[n];
```

because `n` depends on what the user types.

The solution is to cast the void pointer arguments into pointers to `unsigned char`, and then manipulate the `unsigned char *`

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) a, 
                  *q = (unsigned char *) b, 
                  tmp;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        tmp = p[i];
        p[i] = q[i];
        q[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

But since you're using C++, it is a better idea to use templates.

Comment: The MS C++ compiler allows VLAs and the MS C compiler does not, so the reasoning in your first paragraph may not be correct

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MSVC is the only major C compiler that doesn't support your code. To support all compilers you can write:

```
void swap(void * vp1, void * vp2, int size)
{
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    if ( buffer )
    {
        memcpy(buffer, vp1, size);
        memcpy(vp1, vp2, size);
        memcpy(vp2, buffer, size);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

Note: This way is simple in code but there may be more efficient options, especially if you are typically only swapping small buffers.

Comment: It says value of void * can't be allocated to value of char *

Comment: @Kyoko that means you're using a C++ compiler.  You either need to figure out how to invoke your C compiler, or rewrite your question to be a C++ question.